# Jenkins shell hiding stacktrace loses curl output

Tags: bash, jenkins, sh, jenkins-pipeline, stack-trace

I am trying to hide stacktrace from the following script:

```
def status = "false"
  while (status.equals("false")) {
      sleep 5
      status = sh(
            script: "curl -s -H 'Accept: application/json' http://my.ip | jq \'.completed\' ",
            returnStdout: true
      ).trim()
    echo "status: ${status}"
  }
```

Output:

```
+ curl -s -H 'Accept: application/json' 'http://my.ip'
+ jq .completed
status: true
```

If I only want to see the output message I have to write "set +x" in the scripts body. But this results in status returning as NULL.

```
status = sh(
      script:'''
      set +x
      script: "curl -s -H 'Accept: application/json' http://my.ip | jq \'.completed\'
      ''',
      returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

Output:

```
status: NULL
```

Why does the output get lost and is there any other way to remove the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix here is that I declared multi line script wrong. For this case it should use double quotes not single. So the solution:

```
script: """
  my 
  script
  here
""",
```